# Как удалить div по клику на кнопку в нем?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код.

```
<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>

<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>
```

Как удалить div по клику на кнопку в нем? Например 2 или 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$('.del').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Нет, я нужно кликнуть на id="del" но тогда все удаляется, и кликается только на первую кнопку.

Comment: Я поправил ответ

Comment: А класс кнопке можно назначить?

Comment: да, главное чтобы он одинаковый был.

Comment: Ну если у кнопки есть класс del, тогда проще. Поправил код.

Answer (score 2):

`ID` должен быть уникальным.
Используйте класс:

```js
function remove(){
  let w = this.closest('.form'), br = w.nextElementSibling;
  
  if(br.nodeType === 1 && br.nodeName === 'BR')
    br.remove();
  
  w.remove();
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.del')).forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', remove));

/*
jQuery style:

$('.del').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent('.form').remove();
});
*/
```

```html
<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button class="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>

<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button class="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button class="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>

<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button class="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" ></textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button class="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";
window.onload = function(){
 var _cover = document.querySelector("div.cover");
  _cover.addEventListener("click",function(){
  var event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if(target.parentNode.tagName == "DIV"){
  target.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  };
  },false);
}//конец функции
```

```html
<div class="cover">
 <div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" >textarea_1</textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>

<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" >textarea_2</textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" >textarea_3</textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" >textarea_4</textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>


<div class="form"><textarea class="ptext" >textarea_5</textarea><br><input class="plink" type="text" value=""/><button id="del" >Удалить</button></div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте этот вариант.

Comment: Просто идеальное выполнение делегирования. Главное мимо кнопки не щёлкать :)